# Display links to new webpages created

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I'm building a website with Python (using heroku) and I would like to create a "newest submissions" section. That is, when I create a new `@app.route(blah)` in my Python app, I want a link to the new page to show up under the "newest submissions" section on my homepage.

Is this possible?

EDIT: here's my code

```
import os
import json
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for
from werkzeug.routing import Map, Rule, NotFound, RequestRedirect, BaseConverter

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return  render_template('welcome.html')

@app.route('/about', endpoint='about')
def index():
    return  render_template('about.html')

@app.route('/contact', endpoint='contact')
def index():
    return  render_template('contact.html')

@app.route('/all-links', endpoint='all-links')
def all_links():
    links = []
    for rule in app.url_map.iter_rules():
        url = url_for(rule.endpoint)
        links.append((url, rule.endpoint))
    return render_template('all_links.html', links=links)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Bind to PORT if defined, otherwise default to 5000.
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

and the all_links.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>links</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            {% for url, endpoint in links %}
            <li><a href="{{ url }}">{{ endpoint }}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `Is this possible?` Yes. You'll probably get better responses if you post some code for what you have already tried.

Comment: At this point, I'm looking more for some direction, than an actual "here is the answer" answer. Can i do this completely in flask? Do i use a combination of python coding and flask coding in my main app.py file?

Answer (score 10):

All the routes for an application are stored on [`app.url_map`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.url_map) which is an instance of [`werkzeug.routing.Map`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/routing/#werkzeug.routing.Map).  That being said, you can iterate over the [`Rule`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/routing/#werkzeug.routing.Rule) instances by using the [`iter_rules`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/routing/#werkzeug.routing.Map.iter_rules) method:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/all-links")
def all_links():
    links = []
    for rule in app.url_map.iter_rules():
        if len(rule.defaults) >= len(rule.arguments):
            url = url_for(rule.endpoint, **(rule.defaults or {}))
            links.append((url, rule.endpoint))
    return render_template("all_links.html", links=links)
```

```
{# all_links.html #}
<ul>
{% for url, endpoint in links %}
<li><a href="{{ url }}">{{ endpoint }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: so, the for loop in the code you posted takes all the routes in the app.url_map and puts them in the links list. But what is the point of render_template("all_links.html", links=links)? Doesn't that make it so that some page located at herokuapp.com/all-links returns the all_links.html when someone goes there?

Comment: @CrossGameChat - the last line is just an example - I'll add an example Jinja template for the `all_links` template.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! I'm still getting a 500 internal server error "The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application." I updated the post with the code for my app.py and all_links.html

Comment: @CrossGameChat - the example I gave you was missing the key word - `return`.  Add `return` to `render_template` and give it another try.  I've updated my example as well.

Comment: Again, thanks a lot for the help. I'm still getting the error (even tried recopying your code). I'll show the code to one of my professors and see if they can figure out what is wrong. It's a little hard for me to understand the flask and werkzeug documentation.

Comment: @CrossGameChat - you hadn't imported `url_for` from Flask in your example - I've updated my code with a working version.

Comment: I get an error too when it gets to the rule for static content, it cannot get url_for(rule.endpoint) on it. It raises a BuildError(endpoint, values, method) exception. I'll be trying to find a work around...

Comment: @CrossGameChat - you need to make sure that your rule has all its arguments filled.  I've updated my example.