# Get list of all routes defined in the Flask app

Tags: python, flask

I have a complex Flask-based web app.  There are lots of separate files with view functions.  Their URLs are defined with the `@app.route('/...')` decorator.  Is there a way to get a list of all the routes that have been declared throughout my app?  Perhaps there is some method I can call on the `app` object?

Answer (score 196, accepted):

All the routes for an application are stored on [`app.url_map`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.url_map) which is an instance of [`werkzeug.routing.Map`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/routing/#werkzeug.routing.Map).  You can iterate over the [`Rule`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/routing/#werkzeug.routing.Rule) instances by using the [`iter_rules`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/routing/#werkzeug.routing.Map.iter_rules) method:

```
from flask import Flask, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

def has_no_empty_params(rule):
    defaults = rule.defaults if rule.defaults is not None else ()
    arguments = rule.arguments if rule.arguments is not None else ()
    return len(defaults) >= len(arguments)


@app.route("/site-map")
def site_map():
    links = []
    for rule in app.url_map.iter_rules():
        # Filter out rules we can't navigate to in a browser
        # and rules that require parameters
        if "GET" in rule.methods and has_no_empty_params(rule):
            url = url_for(rule.endpoint, **(rule.defaults or {}))
            links.append((url, rule.endpoint))
    # links is now a list of url, endpoint tuples
```

See [Display links to new webpages created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151161/display-links-to-new-webpages-created/13161594#13161594) for a bit more information.

Comment: Sweet!  Except I had an issue with the line `url = url_for(rule.endpoint)`. I just got this error `BuildError: ('DeleteEvent', {}, None)`.    Instead, to get the url I just did `url = rule.rule`.  Any idea why your method doesn't work for me?

Comment: @J-bob - most likely the route associated with `DeleteEvent` has a *required* parameter - you can either special-case that one or filter out any rules where `len(rule.arguments) > len(rule.defaults)`

Comment: Oh I think I get it. `url_for` can't generate the URL for that methid without a parameter, right? OK, but it looks like my method works anyway, it just keeps that portion if the URL as a parameter. Thanks!

Comment: This is helpful! You can do a simple check by invoking `python` REPL environment, loading your main flask application, e.g, `import main` and directly displaying its url_map, `main.app.url_map`. It'll gives you list of all defined routes

Comment: This is a great start. Any suggestions for how to create a fully self-documenting flask-based web service, where all of the parameters (such as ?spam="eggs") are listed? Perhaps this info can be extracted from a docstring of an implementing method.

Comment: Instead of use `url_for(rule.endpoint)` use `rule.rule` that is much better beacause solve cases where you have more than one route for the same method.

Comment: Ty for `rule.endpoint` !!!!!!!

Answer (score 168):

I just met the same question. Those solutions above are too complex.
Just open a new shell under your project:

```
>>> from app import app
>>> app.url_map
```

The first '*app*' is my project script: *app.py*,
another is my web's name.

*(this solution is for the tiny web with a little route)*

Comment: This probably does not answer the question directly. But it sure deserves many more upvotes.

Comment: This answer is great for not requiring you to add any code to your application. I used it to get the answer I wanted in seconds without rebuilding my code.

Comment: " Is there a way to get a list of all the routes that have been declared throughout my app?" I think this answers the question directly and should be the accepted answer. So easy. Thanks.

Comment: I don't really see how this any simpler or clearer than the accepted answer. It's suggesting the same approach, but takes longer to get to the point and doesn't show how to iterate over the `Map` instance or access any of the properties of the `Rule`s it contains, without which you can't actually do anything useful.

Answer (score 65):

I make a helper method on my `manage.py`:

```
@manager.command
def list_routes():
    import urllib
    output = []
    for rule in app.url_map.iter_rules():

        options = {}
        for arg in rule.arguments:
            options[arg] = "[{0}]".format(arg)

        methods = ','.join(rule.methods)
        url = url_for(rule.endpoint, **options)
        line = urllib.unquote("{:50s} {:20s} {}".format(rule.endpoint, methods, url))
        output.append(line)

    for line in sorted(output):
        print line
```

It solves the the missing argument by building a dummy set of options.  The output looks like:

```
CampaignView:edit              HEAD,OPTIONS,GET     /account/[account_id]/campaigns/[campaign_id]/edit
CampaignView:get               HEAD,OPTIONS,GET     /account/[account_id]/campaign/[campaign_id]
CampaignView:new               HEAD,OPTIONS,GET     /account/[account_id]/new
```

Then to run it:

`python manage.py list_routes`

For more on manage.py checkout: http://flask-script.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: The above works very well.  Just change `urllib.unquote` to `urllib.parse.unquote` and `print line` to `print(line)` and it works in python 3.x as well.

Comment: This doesn't work for non-string arguments, I recommend to use John Jiang's answer instead.

Answer (score 65):

Apparently, since version 0.11, [Flask has a built-in CLI](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/cli/). One of the built-in commands lists the routes:

```
FLASK_APP='my_project.app' flask routes
```

Comment: `flask urls` for me (0.12.1). Saw that in `flask --help` but I don't see routes or urls on the CLI page

Comment: routes seems to be removed in flask 1.1.2

Comment: @JerryJi That does not look right.  `routes` is still there in 1.1.2

Answer (score 46):

Similar to Jonathan's answer I opted to do this instead. I don't see the point of using url_for as it will break if your arguments are not string e.g. float

```
@manager.command
def list_routes():
    import urllib

    output = []
    for rule in app.url_map.iter_rules():
        methods = ','.join(rule.methods)
        line = urllib.unquote("{:50s} {:20s} {}".format(rule.endpoint, methods, rule))
        output.append(line)

    for line in sorted(output):
        print(line)
```

Answer (score 20):

Use cli command in Directory where your flask project is.

```sh
flask routes
```

Comment: This is the most convenient one, good answer.

Answer (score 9):

Since you did not specify that it has to be run command-line, the following could easily be returned in json for a dashboard or other non-command-line interface.  The result and the output really shouldn't be commingled from a design perspective anyhow.  It's bad program design, even if it is a tiny program. The result below could then be used in a web application, command-line, or anything else that ingests json.

You also didn't specify that you needed to know the python function associated with each route, so this more precisely answers your original question.

I use below to add the output to a monitoring dashboard myself.  If you want the available route methods (GET, POST, PUT, etc.), you would need to combine it with other answers above.

Rule's **repr**() takes care of converting the required arguments in the route.

```
def list_routes():
    routes = []

    for rule in app.url_map.iter_rules():
        routes.append('%s' % rule)

    return routes
```

The same thing using a list comprehension:

```
def list_routes():
    return ['%s' % rule for rule in app.url_map.iter_rules()]
```

Sample output:

```
{
  "routes": [
    "/endpoint1", 
    "/nested/service/endpoint2", 
    "/favicon.ico", 
    "/static/<path:filename>"
  ]
}
```

Comment: `TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, dict, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a list.`

Comment: `return "\n<br/>\n".join(map(escape, app.url_map.iter_rules()))` for a plain HTML.

Answer (score 6):

If you need to access the view functions themselves, then instead of `app.url_map`, use [`app.view_functions`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.view_functions).

Example script:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/foo/bar')
def route1():
    pass

@app.route('/qux/baz')
def route2():
    pass

for name, func in app.view_functions.items():
    print(name)
    print(func)
    print()
```

Output from running the script above:

```
static
<bound method _PackageBoundObject.send_static_file of <Flask '__main__'>>

route1
<function route1 at 0x128f1b9d8>

route2
<function route2 at 0x128f1ba60>
```

(Note the inclusion of the "static" route, which is created automatically by Flask.)

Answer (score 4):

You can view all the Routes via flask shell by running the following commands after exporting or setting FLASK_APP environment variable.

`flask shell
app.url_map`

Answer (score 3):

inside your flask app do:

```
flask shell
>>> app.url_map
Map([<Rule '/' (OPTIONS, HEAD, GET) -> helloworld>,
 <Rule '/static/<filename>' (OPTIONS, HEAD, GET) -> static>])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
print(app.url_map)
```

That, is, if your Flask application name is 'app'.

It's an attribute of the instance of the Flask App.

See https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/api/#flask.Flask.url_map