# Is there a way to easily define routes for multiple standard pages in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

While making a web app in Flask, I'm finding I have a big list of views that look exactly like these:

```
@app.route('/home', methods=['GET'])
@require_login
def home():
    return render_template("home.html")

@app.route('/files', methods=['GET'])
@require_login
def files():
    return render_template("files.html")
```

Is there some way I could make a list like ['home','files'] and generate all of those simple views from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `routes` and `templates` names match, you can do the following:

```
@app.route('/home', methods=['GET'])
@app.route('/files', methods=['GET'])
@require_login
def just_render():
    file_name = request.path.replace('/', '')
    template = '{file_name}.html'.format(file_name=file_name)

    return render_template(template)
```

i.e. get the requested path from [`request.path`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Request.path), remove unwanted `/` and then format the template name.

**EDIT**

To answer your question from the comments:

> Is there any way I could compress the list of routes?

I would amend a bit *@Sean Vieira*'s answer from the comments:

```
@app.route('/<path>', methods=['GET'])
@require_login
def just_render(path):
    if path in ['home', 'files', 'about', 'contact']:
         template = '{file_name}.html'.format(file_name=path)
         return render_template(template)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much!

Comment: Is there any way I could compress the list of routes? Like a simple_renders = ['/home','/files'], if request is in simple_renders, @app.route(request) kind of thing?

Comment: Yes, just make it a parameter:  `@app.route('/{path}') @require_login def template_route(path): return render_template(path + '.html')`

Comment: Thanks again, this is perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, similar to Django, you can have a file to store your centralised urls in Flask. This can be used to link each of your url routes to the appropriate view function.  As per the [Flask documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/lazyloading/), you could do something along the following lines:

**views.py**

```
@require_login
def home():
    return render_template("home.html")

@require_login
def files():
    return render_template("files.html")
```

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from myapp import views

app = Flask(__name__)

app.add_url_rule('/home', view_func=views.home, methods=['GET'])
app.add_url_rule('/files', view_func=views.files, methods=['GET'])
```

Comment: This is good information so I upvoted you, but it doesn't actually reduce the amount of code, it's still 4 lines per route, just spread across two files.  It's actually more code since @app.route('/home', methods=['GET']) is replaced with app.add_url_rule('/home', view_func=views.home, methods=['GET'])

Comment: It doesn't *reduce the amount of code*, but it does *make the code clearer* and *easier to maintain*. The solution that you have accepted works well, but it might be restrictive if you want to change any of your view functions, template names or urls moving forward.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do this is to use a path variable:

```
@app.route('/{path}')
@require_login
def template_route(path):
    return render_template(path + '.html')
```

This makes it easy to expose new templates without having to write extra handlers that repeat the same logic over and over.

Another way to do it is to make a factory:

```
def TemplateRenderer(app):
    def register_template_endpoint(name):
        @app.route('/' + name, endpoint=name)
        @require_login
        def route_handler():
            return render_template(name + '.html')
    return register_template_endpoint
```

Then you can use it as follows:

```
register_template_endpoint = TemplateRenderer(app)
for path in ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']:
    register_template_endpoint(path)
```

The advantage of this pattern is that each template has its own endpoint in your application, so you can use `url_for('a')` rather than `url_for('template_route', path='a')` as you would for the path variable above.

Comment: Thank you for this factory! I've wondered for a long time how to accomplish this for simple routes without forms. Very happy to no longer need to copy-paste the simplest route and replace the same text in 4 different places.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on [@Sean Viera's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34782633/3295556) above, as I wanted the paths to be automatically added based on HTML files in my templates folder. The challenge is that you'll get an error if you autogenerate an endpoint that already exists in a custom route. I also used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53660799/3295556) to achieve the following. Note this must be included after all existing routes to avoid the `AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function`.

```
def TemplateRenderer(app):
    def register_template_endpoint(name, endpoint):
        @app.route('/' + name, endpoint=endpoint)
        def route_handler():
            title = name.replace('-', ' ').capitalize()
            return render_template(name + '.html', title=title)
    return register_template_endpoint

endpoints = []
for r in app.url_map._rules:
    endpoints.append(r.endpoint)

template_list = []
for f in os.listdir('app/templates'):
    if f.endswith('html') and not f.startswith('_'): # I have partial templates that begin with '_' and don't need routes
        template_list.append(f[0:-5])

register_template_endpoint = TemplateRenderer(app)
for path in template_list:
    endpoint = path.replace('-','_') # my templates and routes use '-' while endpoints must use '_'
    if endpoint not in endpoints:
        register_template_endpoint(path, endpoint)
```

This replaces a plethora of routes that look like this:

```
@app.route('/about')
def about():
    return render_template('about.html', title="About")
```