# Unit testing a Flask app with LiveServerTestCase

Tags: python, selenium, flask

I'm on Python 3.4. I'm trying to write tests using Selenium. I'm using https://flask-testing.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#testing-with-liveserver as a template. Here's the way I have my class set up:

```
class APITestCase(LiveServerTestCase):
    def create_app(self):
        app = create_app('testing')
        return app 

    def setUp(self):
        self.display = Display(visible=0, size=(1024, 768))
        self.display.start()
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()
        self.display.stop()
```

And for my only test:

```
    def test_register(self):
        register_link = self.get_server_url() + url_for('register')
        self.driver.get(register_link)
```

I get a 404. Even using the requests library, I still get a 404.

I'm certain that /register is defined for the `register` view function because I'm printing out the routes right before I call `self.driver.get(register_link)` using the method here: [get a list of all routes defined in the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13317536/get-a-list-of-all-routes-defined-in-the-app)

Furthermore, if I initialize a test client using `self.client = app.test_client()` in the `create_app` function, I'm able to access routes normally using `self.client.get` or `self.client.post` but that defeats the purpose of Selenium.

Comment: What is the value of `register_link` when the test runs?

Comment: `http://localhost:5001/register` which is correct.

Comment: And if you access it using a web browser, you get something other than a 404?

Comment: As far as I know, when using the command `python manage.py test` to test the app, it only instantiates the app for the duration of the test. The `setUp` and `tearDown` methods call the `create_app` method for each test. So, I can't access with a web browser. It's only up for a few seconds at a time when doing these tests.