# Route doesn't exist

Tags: python, flask

I have the following code on my service and when requested the return is always 404.

```
@app.route('/v1/auth/service', methods=['POST'])
def verifyAuthService():
    data = request.get_json()
```

But in the log file, the service returns 404.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [TIMEVALUE] "POST /v1/auth/service HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

But it works when I use other route. I have checked if the route path or method name are duplicated and didn't find anything.

I request the service method with the following code:

```
r = requests.post("http://myservice.com:5001/v1/auth/service", json=jPayload)
```

Comment: Are you sure you are accessing it via POST?

Comment: r = requests.post("http://myservice.com:1323/v1/auth/service", json=jPayload)

This is how I call the service method.

I will add it in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe was a newbie error, in my `init.py` file, I haven't imported `auth_services.py`.

The `/v1/auth/service` route wasn't interpreted by python so, the route was inaccessible.

Comment: See this question, it's helpful for debugging problems like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13317536/get-a-list-of-all-routes-defined-in-the-app

Answer (score 0):

Can you try building the URL with below code and match if the route is pointing to exactly same URL which you have called.

```
from flask import Flask, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/v1/auth/service', methods=['POST'])
def verifyAuthService():
    data = request.get_json()

with app.test_request_context():
    print url_for('verifyAuthService')
```

Hope this helps!