# Get list of all routes defined in the Falcon app

Tags: python, routes, falconframework

I have RESTful routes in a Falcon app defined as below simplified codes.
My question is how to get list of all routes with their mapped handlers?

My [google search](https://www.google.com.vn/search?q=python%203%20falcon%20get%20all%20routes%20mapping&oq=python%203%20falcon%20get%20all%20routes%20mapping&aqs=chrome..69i57.16823j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) results in little-helpful rpages - one similar issue resolved for Flask app [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13317536/248616) but no page talking about Falcon.

```
api = falcon.API(middleware=middleware)
api.add_route('/v1/model_names1', SomeHandlerMappingResource1())
api.add_route('/v1/model_names2', SomeHandlerMappingResource2())

class SomeHandlerMappingResource1:
    def on_get(self, req, resp):
        pass # some biz logic of GET method
    def on_post(self, req, resp):
        pass # some biz logic of POST method
    # etc.

class SomeHandlerMappingResource2:
    pass # similar to handler resource 1 above
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below code will return a list of tuple with URL and their respective Resources:

```
def get_all_routes(api):
    routes_list = []

    def get_children(node):
        if len(node.children):
            for child_node in node.children:
                get_children(child_node)
        else:
            routes_list.append((node.uri_template, node.resource))
    [get_children(node) for node in api._router._roots]
    return routes_list
```

#### Output

```
[
    ('/v1/things', <v1.v1_app.ThingsResource object at 0x7f555186de10>), 
    ('/v2/things', <v2.v2_app.ThingsResource object at 0x7f5551871470>), 
    ('/v3/things/{name}', <v3.v3_app.ThingsResource object at 0x7f5551871ba8>)
]
```

> I have read the package and derived this, however, I don't know any builtin method that will return this result.

---

If you don't like the above function, You can achieve something similar by extending the API class.

I have made a Github repo for versioning the Falcon app, from which you can get an idea of separating the URLs and their relative resources. [Github Link](https://github.com/paneru-rajan/falcon-url-versioning)

You can have a [list of routes](https://github.com/paneru-rajan/falcon-url-versioning/blob/master/v1/urls.py) and add them by Extended the [API class](https://github.com/paneru-rajan/falcon-url-versioning/blob/master/settings/api.py)

URLs and Resources will be like:

```
from v1.v1_app import things

urls = [
    ('/things', things),
]
```

Comment: Great! I'll check this and return to vote yours as accepted if it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a little empty scope in your logic, I've implemented and in some cases it doesn't reach some endpoints. This is my version, (of course based on yours):

```
def get_all_routes(api: App) -> List:
    routes_list = []

    def get_children(node):
        if len(node.children):
            if node.uri_template:
                routes_list.append((node.uri_template, node.resource))
            for child_node in node.children:
                get_children(child_node)
        else:
            routes_list.append((node.uri_template, node.resource))

    [get_children(node) for node in api._router._roots]
    return routes_list
```