Getting 404 Not Found error when trying to access Flask route via Postman
I'm developing a web application using Flask, and I'm facing an issue when trying to access a specific route via Postman. The route in question is responsible for registering a new news article in the database. However, when sending a POST request to the '/cadastrar_noticia' route using Postman, I'm getting a "404 Not Found" error.
Here's the relevant code from my Flask application:
@user_bp.route('/cadastrar_noticia', methods=['POST'])
def cadastrarNoticia():
    if not session.get('logged_in'):
        return jsonify("Usuário nao está logado no sistema")
    
    data = request.get_json()

    # Verifica se todos os campos obrigatórios estão presentes nos dados da solicitação
    required_fields = ['titulo', 'resumo', 'noticia', 'site_id', 'categoria_id']
    for field in required_fields:
        if field not in data or not data[field]:
            return jsonify({'error': f'Campo {field} ausente ou vazio!'}), 400
        
    try:
        conn = connect_db()
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        # Insere a nova notícia no banco de dados
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Sites_noticias (titulo, resumo, noticia, site_id, categoria_id) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s) RETURNING *",
                       (data['titulo'], data['resumo'], data['noticia'], data['site_id'], data['categoria_id']))
        
        new_noticia = cursor.fetchone()
        conn.commit()

    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({'error': str(e)}), 500
    finally:
        if 'conn' in locals():
            conn.close()

    return jsonify({'success': True, 'message': 'Notícia cadastrada com sucesso!', 'noticia': new_noticia}), 201


postman result
I've already checked if the route is defined correctly in my Flask code, and it seems to be fine. Additionally, I've verified that the Flask application is running and the server is accessible on port 5000.
I've also tried accessing other routes defined in my Flask application via Postman, and they work correctly. It seems like the issue is only with this specific route.
Can someone help me understand why I'm receiving this error and how I can fix it?

check all the routes added to your flask app , and see if the current endpoint present there or not .  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13317536/get-list-of-all-routes-defined-in-the-flask-app

Can you show us how you initialize the blueprint and also how you attach the blueprint to the app in the factory function?
