# URL of a wsgi_app Flask app using DispatcherMiddleware

Tags: python, flask, wsgi

I have two application factory functions - one creates the "customer" app, and the other creates the "admin" backend app. Both of the factory functions essentially do what is described [here](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flasky/blob/master/app/__init__.py) - create a flask app and register some extensions to it and then add some blueprints(with a url_prefix). I glue the two apps together via the `create_combined_app()` from below. It is the return value of that function which I register with my Flask-Script's `Manager`.

```
def create_combined_app(config_name):
    customer_app = create_customer_app(config_name)
    admin_app = create_admin_app(config_name)

    from werkzeug.wsgi import DispatcherMiddleware

    customer_app.wsgi_app = DispatcherMiddleware(customer_app.wsgi_app, {
        '/admin': admin_app
    })

    return customer_app
```

And then this is how I run it.

```
def make_me_an_app():
    return create_combined_app(config)

manager = Manager(make_me_an_app)
...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

I want to do some testing which involves getting all GET routes of my app and making sure they load. I followed the example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151161/display-links-to-new-webpages-created/13161594#13161594), but I only see the urls of the **customer** app, and none of the urls from the **admin** backend.

```
@main.route("/site-map")
def site_map():
    from flask import current_app, jsonify
    links = []
    app = current_app
    for rule in app.url_map.iter_rules():
        if "GET" in rule.methods and has_no_empty_params(rule):
            url = url_for(rule.endpoint, **(rule.defaults or {}))
            links.append((url, rule.endpoint))
    return jsonify(links)
```

The admin backend works when I try to access it from the browser - it all works nicely, except that I don't see the admin's urls when I call /site-map.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think **DispatcherMiddleware** create separate apps. Which mean you created customer_app and admin_app. Those 2 live as standalone. They don't know each others, therefor current_app is just the show customer_app.

Here is the describe from Flask http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/appdispatch/

[image]